# boost::beast ssl tcp stream: gracefully disconnect and then reconnect

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I have a `boost::beast` ssl stream data member:

```
class HttpsClient
{
    ...
    asio::ssl::context _ssl_ctx;
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> _stream;
};
```

At construction I initialise the stream with an `asio::io_context` and an ssl context as follows:

```
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;

ssl::context sslContext()
{
    ssl::context ssl_ctx {ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    ssl_ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::context::verify_peer | ssl::context::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
    ssl_ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
    boost::certify::enable_native_https_server_verification(ssl_ctx);
    return ssl_ctx;
}

HttpsClient::HttpsClient(asio::io_context& ctx)
    : _ssl_ctx(sslContext())
    , _stream(ctx, _ssl_ctx)
{}
```

My connect function synchronously resolves the endpoint, connects to it, and performs the SSL handshake.

```
void HttpsClient::connect(const std::string& host, std::uint16_t port, const std::string& path)
{
    tcp::resolver resolver {_stream.get_executor()};
    tcp::resolver::results_type end_point = resolver.resolve(host, std::to_string(port));

    beast::get_lowest_layer(_stream).connect(end_point);
    beast::get_lowest_layer(_stream).socket().set_option(tcp::no_delay {true});

    SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(_stream.native_handle(), host.c_str());
    _stream.handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);
}
```

Once connected, I start an `async_read`, and when I want to send a request, I use the synchronously version:

```
void HttpsClient::write(beast::http::request<beast::http::string_body>& request)
{
    request.prepare_payload();
    http::write(_stream, request);
}
```

This is all works as expected.

The problem I'm coming up against is that I would like to disconnect and then reconnect the stream.

I have tried several different ways to close the connection:

*Cancel outstanding async_read and shutdown the stream:*

```
_stream.next_layer().cancel();
_stream.shutdown();
```

Once the `shutdown` completes I am seemingly able to connect again, but attempts to write to the stream fail with `"protocol is shutdown"`.

After receiving `"protocol is shutdown"` any attempts to reconnect receive `"Operation canceled"`

*Cancel outstanding async_read and close the underlying TCP stream*:

```
_stream.next_layer().cancel();
_stream.next_layer().close();
```

Once the `close` completes I am still seemingly able to connect again, but now attempts to write to the stream fail with `"wrong version number"`.

After receiving `"wrong version number"` any attempts to reconnect receive `"unspecified system error"`

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to disconnect my stream, and then reconnect and reuse it?
- If so, what procedure do I need to do to allow this?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1778) relating to websocket, but possibly the ssl stream has similar requirements, says to recreate the entire stream... suggests reusing a disconnected stream is not possible

Comment: I think you might usefully promote the comment into a self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1778) relating to websocket, but possibly the ssl stream has similar requirements, says to recreate the entire stream... suggests reusing a disconnected stream is not possible.

Certainly recreating the stream does work, which suggests this is indeed the case